# how to implement horizontal scrolling/paging view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift

As you can see in my attached screenshot. There are 2 buttons in my screen: Videos and Friends.

Whenever user touch on button `Videos`, the following view will slide-to-left to show video content. And when user touch on button `Friends`, it will slide-to-right to show friend list.

I found a tutorial on Objective-C at http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers. I followed step by step and always receive the error like this:

```
'Application tried to present modally an active controller <KaptrProject.ProfileViewController: 0x7ffcb2825910>.'
```

My project based on Swift and I think that Swift doesn't permit to change views by using `transitionFromViewController()`.

Please take a look and help me to solve this problem. Any suggestion or approaching are also welcome.

By the way, Here is the swift code I converted from Obj-c following the tutorial:

```
  //
//  ContainerViewController.swift
//  KaptrProject
//
//  Created by Binh Nguyen on 5/14/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 TrangNguyen. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {
    let SegueIdentifierFirst = "embedFirst"
    let SegueIdentifierSecond = "embedSecond"
    var currentSegue = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        currentSegue = SegueIdentifierFirst;
        performSegueWithIdentifier(currentSegue, sender: nil)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        var destVC = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController

        if segue.identifier == SegueIdentifierFirst {
            if self.childViewControllers.count > 0{
                var currVC = self.childViewControllers.first as UIViewController
                swap(fromVC: currVC as UIViewController, toVC: destVC)
            }else{
                self.addChildViewController(destVC)
                destVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)

                self.view.addSubview(destVC.view)
                destVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
            }
        }else if segue.identifier == SegueIdentifierSecond{
            var currVC = self.childViewControllers.first as UIViewController
            swap(fromVC: currVC, toVC: destVC)
        }

    }

    func swap(#fromVC:UIViewController, toVC :UIViewController){

        toVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height )
        fromVC.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)

        addChildViewController(toVC)

        transitionFromViewController(fromVC, toViewController: toVC, duration: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil, completion:  { finished in
            fromVC.removeFromParentViewController()     
            toVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        })
    }

    func swapVC(){
        println("swap!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        if (currentSegue == SegueIdentifierFirst){
            currentSegue = SegueIdentifierSecond
        }else{
            currentSegue = SegueIdentifierFirst
        }
        performSegueWithIdentifier(currentSegue, sender: nil)

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not using [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html) ? It will offer to you exactly what you are looking for, plus a number of other page transition animations. A good tutorial where you can start can be found [here](http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-tutorial-using-uipageviewcontroller-create-content-slider-objective-cswift/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do with container view(Child View) . 
add and remove child view controller accordingly